# PHP preg_replace To Replace Hyperlink with H1

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm terrible at writing regular expressions so am looking for some help.

I have the following string:

```
<li class="current-menu-item"><a title="Site Name" href="http://www.example.com/">Home</a></li>
```

An want to replace the hyperlink with a H1.

Is there a simple way to do this using regular expressions, bearing in mind the title, hyperlink and anchor text change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/<a[^>]*>(\w+)<\/a>/', '<h1>$1</h1>', $subject);
```

']' will match all characters except '>', '*' means it will match zero or more occurences of character(s) in front of it, then '>' will be after that, then it will capture everything inside (), '\w' will match any word character, + will match at least one occurence of character in front of it and then '' will appear (forward slashes need to be escaped).

$subject could be whole HTML document or just your string.

Comment: It worked! Removing the g off the end of the string made it work. Would you mind explaining how your answer works?

Comment: My bad, I forgot there is preg_replace_all() method to replace all occurences.

Comment: Look at the complex857's answer. His solution uses DOMDocument class, which is much better than using Regex.

Answer (score 1):

I would discourage the use of regexps for this if your input is non-trivial. Multiline html tags, non-well-formed input, embeded tags can throw a monkey wrench into your solution all too easy. Try using the DOM classes instead:

```
$in = '<li class="current-menu-item"><a title="Site Name" href="http://www.example.com/">Home</a></li>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($in);

// you can use any method to select the nodes in interest, if you need more power use xpath.
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a) {
    $replacement = $dom->createElement('h1');
    // poor man's innerHTML
    foreach ($a->childNodes as $cn) {
        $replacement->appendChild($cn);
    }   
    $a->parentNode->replaceChild($replacement, $a);
}

print $dom->saveHTML();
```